# Pandas if statement does not work when passing through multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Just want to understand why this isn't working.

```
def abc(row):
    abc_1 = row[11]
    abc_2 = row[12]
    
    if abc_1>0 and abc_2>0:
        return 'abc 1 and 2'
    elif abc_1>0 and abc_2 ==0:
        return 'abc_1 only'
    elif abc_1 ==0 and abc_2>0:
        return 'abc_2 only'
    else: return 'No abc'
```

I've converted both columns to numeric using:

```
df['abc_1'] = df['abc_1'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors = 'coerce')

df['abc_2'] = df['abc_2'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors = 'coerce')
```

when I do:

```
df.apply(abc, axis='columns')
```

I get all values as 'No abc' even when there are instances where abc_1 >0 and abc_2 ==0

I've also made sure I've indexed the values in row[] correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider sharing your dataframe and your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this dataframe:

```
# df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.NaN, 0, 1], (10, 2)),
#                   columns=['abc_1', 'abc_2'])
>>> df
   abc_1  abc_2
0    1.0    NaN
1    0.0    1.0
2    0.0    0.0
3    NaN    NaN
4    NaN    1.0
5    0.0    0.0
6    0.0    1.0
7    NaN    1.0
8    1.0    0.0
9    1.0    0.0
```

Your function:

```
def abc(row):
    abc_1 = row['abc_1']  # <- HERE the column name
    abc_2 = row['abc_2']  # <- HERE the column name

    if abc_1>0 and abc_2>0:
        return 'abc 1 and 2'
    elif abc_1>0 and abc_2 ==0:
        return 'abc_1 only'
    elif abc_1 ==0 and abc_2>0:
        return 'abc_2 only'
    else: return 'No abc'
```

The output:

```
>>> df.apply(abc, axis='columns')
0        No abc
1    abc_2 only
2        No abc
3        No abc
4        No abc
5        No abc
6    abc_2 only
7        No abc
8    abc_1 only
9    abc_1 only
dtype: object
```

Alternative output filling `NaN` by 0:

```
>>> df.fillna(0).apply(abc, axis='columns')
0    abc_1 only
1    abc_2 only
2        No abc
3        No abc
4    abc_2 only
5        No abc
6    abc_2 only
7    abc_2 only
8    abc_1 only
9    abc_1 only
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, thanks. This works for the sample df but my df has NaN values. Could this be the reason why my values are all 'No abc' ?

Comment: I updated my answer with NaN values. Obviously, if you have NaN, neither of your conditions will match. because NaN is not greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Maybe you want to fill NaN by 0? In this case, use `df.fillna(0).apply(abc, axis='columns')`. I updated my answer with this case.

Comment: You are a legend df.fillna(0).apply(abc, axis='columns') - this worked. This is why i love StackOverflow!